# how to access router params in getInitialProps stateles component in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

im using nextjs and i have issue in using getInitialProps .

i want to use variables i created in  Post Component in getInitialProps.
you can see my coed :

```
const Post = props => {
  const router = useRouter()
   let id = router.query.id  
   let urlTitle = router.query.title

  return (
    <Layout>
       //somthing
    </Layout>
  )
}


Post.getInitialProps = async () => {

// i want to use {id} and {urlTitle} here

}
```

How can i do it ?!!!

Comment: Your `id` and `urlTitle` is coming from `router` aren't it. Where would you call `Post.getInitialProps` ? Also why is this question tagged with [tag:react-hooks] ?

Comment: @dev_junwen yes they coming from router and i want to use it in Post.getInitialProps

Comment: In which place you call `Post.getInitialProps` ?

Comment: inside Post component itself . 
ts like next js doc exapmle ( https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/fetching-data-for-pages/fetching-batman-shows  )
 but i want use router params insite Post.getInitialProps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to access {query} from getInitialProps

```
const Post = ({id, urlTitle}) => {

  return (
    <Layout>
       //somthing
    </Layout>
  )
}


Post.getInitialProps = async ({ query }) => {

  const { id, title } = query

  return {
    id,
    urlTirle: title
  }

}
```